# Vlookup using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, vlookup

I have a woorkbook with informations that I am adding into word.
Now I need to add a txt that I have to find by use of vlookup (or index match)

My code will not run, and after 6 hours I am near to give up, but hope, that one of you can help me.

The code is:

```
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=(Application.Function.VLookup(Cells((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text).Value, sectionT.Range("ab1:ac5"), 2, 0))
```

My Vba code is placed in anoter workbook. But that has not been a problem so far.

I want to lookup for the text in the cell `(Range((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text)`

I want to lookup in a `range("ab1:ac5")` at another sheet in the same workbook, called sectionT.

My text could be 1.1 and I would like to have the text "Result" typed into word.

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have everything to solve your problem, but I can help you split your problem into more manageable pieces. If you write your code like this:

```
Dim LookupValue, TableArray, OutputText

LookupValue = Cells((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text).Value
Set TableArray = sectionT.Range("ab1:ac5")
OutputText = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, TableArray, 2, 0)

wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=OutputText
```

you can follow it step by step and see where it went wrong. The big issue here is that you wrote `Function` instead of `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: Thank you sam.Unfortunately this is still not working. I used yuor advice to break it down as follows.:  Dim LookupValue As String
Dim TableArray As String
Dim OutputText As String

LookupValue = Cells((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text).Value
TableArray = sectionT.Range("a1:b5")
OutputText = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, TableArray, 2, 0)

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=OutputText
MsgBox (outputxt)

Comment: Hi Sam. Thank you so much. The code is now modified, but Excel returns and says Object Required for the line TableArray = sectionT.Range("a1:b5"). My complete code is : Dim LookupValue As String
Dim TableArray As String
Dim OutputText As String

LookupValue = Cells((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text).Value
TableArray = sectionT.Range("a1:b5")
OutputText = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, TableArray, 2, 0)

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=OutputText
MsgBox (outputxt).

Please observe, that I test with msgbox before I try to send to add into word.

Any suggenstions?

Comment: I missed a `Set` before TableArray

Comment: Sorry, it do not help. Am I declaring right TableArray = String ?

Dim LookupValue As String
Dim TableArray As Integer
Dim OutputText As String

LookupValue = Cells((RowNo + i), ColumnForLevel2Text).Value
Set TableArray = sectionT.Range("a1:b5")
OutputText = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookupValue, TableArray, 2, 0)

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=OutputText
MsgBox (outputxt)